# what typeface is the WeWork logo

Tags: fonts, typefaces

Is it a proprietary typeface created just for the logo? is there anything close that you know of? I tried [matcherator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator) with no luck

Comment: Welcome! Hm, and that logo looks like? Do you have a screenshot of it or an link to it?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that your question shows some *effort*: tell us what you already know and understood; show us what you tried and failed; document what you found when searching the Internet or manual. We have specific requirements for Font ID questions: [https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083] please edit your post to meet them - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logos are often actually drawings. Even when they look out writing they can be outlined text and the outlines are here and there tweaked to make them unique. But this looks like Adobe Garamond Pro Bold, only kerned tightly.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It does look like it Indeed